# Change WooCommerce Word "Product" to Another Word

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have used "Permanent Link" options to change the word "product" to "business" in Woocommerce because I'm using it to build a directory. However, the word "Product" still shows in some areas in "WC Frontend Manager". Any suggestion to change the words. Please check screenshot: https://prnt.sc/twizsz

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a translation module to generate new pot and po files for WooCommerce with your desired changes. If you're not familiar, then I'd recommend using a plugin such as [LocoTranslate](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought about that, but my concern is that since I'm going to translate or have other versions of the website in other languages, that might be a problem considering an experience I have with another website before. It's no possible for the translation plugin to translate a word that is already translated into another language. I'm not sure maybe "LocoTranslate" might be diffrent. I will give it a try.